# Is there any way to route random string to dashboard in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have a question about Codeigniter: Is there any way to check function exists In the controller file and then **route** to the function path or else **route** it to a specific url?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of Dashboard mean in your question.
I just answer how to check function exist or not in controller and route to that function.

In some case, you may need to add a route rule in config/routes.php.

```php
$route['/programme/(.*)$'] = 'programme/programmes/$2';
```

Use `method_exists()` to check if function exist.

```php
class Programme extends CI_Controller {

  public function programmes($sub_part = NULL) {
    if (!empty($sub_part) and method_exists($this, 'programmes_'. $sub_part)) {
            return $this->{'programmes_'. $sub_part}(array_slice(func_get_args(), 1));
        }
    die('bar')
  }

  private function programmes_foo() {
    die('foo')
  }

}
```

When a visitor go to https://www.foobar.com/programme/foo (foo is something affect which function to call), your website should able to show `foo`. If the function is not exist, it show `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = 'yourcontroller/your_function';
```

Source : https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you can change your route into this

```
$route[‘produk/(:num)/(:any)’] = ‘HomeControl/detail_produk/$1/$2’;
```

result from that route it's like this

```
http://www.localhost.com/produk/1/nama-produk-1
```

or maybe you can read the documentation CI 3 in [this link](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) or you can read my reference in Indonesian [this link](https://www.mahadisuta.com/artikel/penerapan-url-routing-pada-framework-codeigniter)